# Word for a "grand, symbolic action"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word would mean "a grand, symbolic action" more specifically, taken in an attempt to prove a point?
For example, I am trying to figure out the word that would fill in the following sentence using the above definition:

> "Charlie gave every last dime he had to charity, just to prove that he didn't care about material possessions. That's one hell of a [*word-for-grand-symbolic-action*]!"

Comment: Here, you have asked two different questions. Please be clear what exactly you want to ask..

Comment: @Sweet72 -  I have edited the question to make it a little more clear. Basically, I want to know what word, using that definition would fit in that sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The gift of the signet ring to Mordecai by Ashuerus was [an impressive **gesture**](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zMVbuD633XEC&pg=PA329&dq=%22an+impressive+gesture%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TjpHUuOvK6KK4wS_44HgCA&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBDgU#v=onepage&q=%22an%20impressive%20gesture%22&f=false) of the honor in which he was held.

Because there's are negative connotation to expressions such as [gesture politics](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gesture+politics), you probably need some kind of *positive* qualifier for this sense ("impressive" in my example, "one hell of a" in OP's).

Comment: also 'grand gesture'--though with connotations of a fumbling protagonist in a bad rom-com

Answer (score 2):

Here, we can reach for a French "coup de something" term.

A brilliantly successful action, or something of that sort, is a *coup d’[éclat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9clat)*.

If we fit this into

> "Charlie gave every last dime he had to charity, just to prove that he didn't care about material possessions. That's one hell of a *coup d’éclat*!"

it seems to work, more or less.

Comment: That's a new one on me! It's [vanishingly rare compared to **coup d’état**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coup+d%E2%80%99%C3%A9tat%2Ccoup+d%E2%80%99%C3%A9clat%2Ccoup+d%E2%80%99etat%2Ccoup+d%E2%80%99eclat&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), and [hasn't been much used for the last couple of centuries](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coup+d%E2%80%99%C3%A9clat%2Ccoup+d%E2%80%99eclat&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), but it does seem to fit the bill.